# Incorrect HTML table generation using JS

Tags: javascript, html

**Hello!**

Why, as a result of this code, all the cells in the table are aligned in one column and don't form a normal table?
Sorry for my bad English, and maybe a stupid question, I started learning JS a few days ago

```js
function start () {
    var size = document.getElementById('test5').value;
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'none';
    for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML += ('<tr>');
        for (var x = 0; x < size ; x++) {
            document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML += ('<td>test</td>');
        }
        document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML += ('</tr>');
    }
}
```

```html
    <div >
        <span id="start"><form action="#">
        <p class="range-field">
            <input  type="range" id="test5" min="3" max="9" value="3"/>
        </p>
        </form><br>
            <button type="button" onclick="start()">start</button></span>
        <table border="1" id="cont"></table>
     </div>
```

Comment: Building HTML with innerHTML is NOT like building a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your loop you assign an *incomplete* HTML string to `innerHTML`. After each assignment, the browser does its best to fix the incomplete HTML.

Consider what happens the first time you do this (for brevity we'll assume `document.getElementById("cont")` has been assigned to a variable named `table`):

```
table.innerHTML += '<tr>';
```

If you then immediately did `console.log(table.innerHTML)` what you would see is not `<tr>`, but `<tr></tr>`. You left that tag open, so the browser closed it for you.

Then, in your loop, you do this:

```
table.innerHTML += '<td>test</td>';
```

Since `table.innerHTML` is already `<tr></tr>`, the new value you're trying to set it to is `<tr></tr><td>test</td>`. That isn't valid HTML—a `<td>` must have a `<tr>` parent—so the browser fixes it for you by wrapping it in a `<tr>`. If you did `console.log(table.innerHTML)` now, you'd see this:

```
<tr></tr>
<tr><td>test</td></tr>
```

...and so on. That's why you get all of your cells in a single column.

The solution is to instead start with a temporary string, and only after you've created a *complete* HTML string, assign it to `innerHTML`:

```js
const table = document.getElementById('cont');
const sizeInput = document.getElementById('test5');

function start() {
  const size = sizeInput.value;
  
  // build a string named `rowsHtml`
  let rowsHtml = '';
  for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
    rowsHtml += '<tr>';
    for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
      rowsHtml += '<td>test</td>';
    }
    rowsHtml += '</tr>';
  }

  // now set innerHTML just once
  cont.innerHTML = rowsHtml;
}
```

```html
<div id="start">
  <input  type="range" id="test5" min="3" max="9" value="3"/>
  <button type="button" onclick="start()">start</button>
</div>
<table border="1" id="cont"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are placing your `<td>`s inside the element with the id of cont. you need to place them inside the `<tr>` instead. Here is a working solution:

```js
function start () {
    var size = document.getElementById('test5').value;
    let table = document.getElementById("cont");
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'none';
    for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        table.innerHTML += ('<tr></tr>');
        for (var x = 0; x < size ; x++) {
        let tr = document.querySelector("#cont tr:last-child");
            tr.innerHTML += ('<td>test</td>');
        }
        document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML += ('</tr>');
    }
}
```

```html
<div >
        <span id="start"><form action="#">
        <p class="range-field">
            <input  type="range" id="test5" min="3" max="9" value="3"/>
        </p>
        </form><br>
            <button type="button" onclick="start()">start</button></span>
        <table border="1"><tbody id="cont"></tbody></table>
     </div>
```